# Recommendation to Shooting Long Videos

Tags: recommendation, video-recording

I'm seeking recommendations on how to shoot a long lecture by a guest speaker that is coming to town. I currently own a Canon t4i. My main question is what do I need to avoid my camera from spazzing out during the lecture. What SD card might I need? Will the battery run out? How to avoid that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The biggest trick you will run in to is the 4GB file size limit and the 30 minute record time limit.  You will need to monitor the recording and resume several times or use a third party software like Magic Lantern to overcome the limitations.  As for battery, there is a DC adapter available that you can buy if battery life is a concern.

Comment: Does this camera stop recording at those points, or merely split the recording into several files?

Answer (score 1):

Using a second DSLR and alternating between them would allow you to edit together continuous coverage, swapping memory cards as you go. Have both cameras on power adapters, not batteries. Don't buy, rent.

Answer (score 0):

AJ Henderson is correct, as far as power, finding a way to plug it to a constant circuit would be the best option. Bring an extension cord, and a surge protector (pref: low-noise) :-)

As far as video capacity... there should be some way you can stream the video out in real time to a close by laptop or something (with lots of HD space, and 7200rpm recomended too).. Since video can fill up space FAST, getting an external drive or two would definitely do the job... again def. get 7200 rpm and you can get 500 Gb fairly cheap these days... I [recommend](http://www.lacie.com/us/products/product.htm?id=10553) ...